# how to query posts to insert in a row

Tags: php, wordpress, zurb-foundation

So I managed to query my posts however they break/not aligned properly underneath after the first 2 columns. So I want to insert 2 posts per row, sorry if my explanation is really bad.[image]

```
$loop = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => 'team') ); ?>

        <?php while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); ?>

            <!-- <div class="large-6 columns"> -->
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="large-3 columns">
                        <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail()) : // Check if thumbnail exists ?>
                            <?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail($page->ID, 'medium'); ?>

                        <?php else: // use this image to fill the thumbnail ?>
                            <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150">
                        <?php endif; ?>
                    </div>

                    <div class="large-9 columns">
                        <div class="panel radius">
                            <h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3>
                                <p><?php the_content(); ?></p>
                                <?php edit_post_link(); // Always handy to have Edit Post Links available ?>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            <!-- </div> -->
        <?php endwhile; ?>
```

Comment: Whats the css framework? Im guessing you need to count iterations and insert </div><div class="row"> every 2 iterations.

Comment: sorry forgot to mention the framework, its foundation zurb. Yeah pretty much, not sure how to do it I've read about array_chunk but I kept getting errors. So I went back to my old code which is the one I posted above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not a zurb user, but i expect you need to start a new row every 2 posts:

```
$loop = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => 'team') ); 
$counter=0;
?>

    <?php while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); $counter++;?>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="large-3 columns">
                    <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail()) : // Check if thumbnail exists ?>
                        <?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail($page->ID, 'medium'); ?>

                    <?php else: // use this image to fill the thumbnail ?>
                        <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150">
                    <?php endif; ?>
                </div>

                <div class="large-9 columns">
                    <div class="panel radius">
                        <h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3>
                            <p><?php the_content(); ?></p>
                            <?php edit_post_link(); // Always handy to have Edit Post Links available ?>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>


            <?php 
              //close row div and start another every 2 posts
              if ($counter%2==0):?>
                </div><div class="row"> 
            <?php endif;?>


    <?php endwhile; ?>
```

Comment: Ahh you're a life save, Thanks that works. You missed <div class="large-6 columns" below the while loop but it works. Thanks.

Comment: Great answer. I have a screencast where I talk about issues with ZURB Foundation and dynamic data, closing rows so you get consistent output, it might be some good additional background information: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UjN_aX84Qco